# wpf classes global?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

IM not a C# programmer by nature but I do ok with it for what i need. Im trying to Learn WPF and my question is, Can I Declare my classes in App.xaml and access it from all of my separate controls? Im primarily interested in this because I would like ot be about to have one LogWriter and let all of them talk to it.

```
<!-- App.xaml -->
<Application x:Class="MyAPP.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:src="clr-namespace:LogWriter"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
 <src:LogWriter x:Name="LogWriter"/> 
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: H.Bs answer is enough. Just to clarify: Resources are Dictionaries. Therefore resources in them are not named, but given a Key. A name is usually necessary in Templates with animations, triggers and ElementName bindings. In the MSDN is a good article about the resource lookup. Read about StaticResource which should be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`x:Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804.aspx), use [`StaticResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189045.aspx) to reference. [`Application.Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resources.aspx) are accessible anywhere in the application.